# difference between proc univariate in sas 9.1 vs sas 9.3

Tags: sas

In SAS 9.1, this code works fine and includes the missing values, which I need. As soon as I ported this program to SAS 9.3, it gave me the wrong minpoint values and excluded the missing values. How do I include the missing values and also why is it giving me the wrong output?

```
data myData;
    input value;
    datalines;    
-2.47 
-4
-5
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
12
;
run;

proc univariate data = myData noprint;
    histogram value /
        barwidth = 0.05
        endpoints = (-2.5 to 2.45 by 0.05)
        outhist = histogram
        nochart;
run;
```

This is the `HISTOGRAM` dataset as output from SAS 9.1, which is correct:

```
MinPoint    Cumpercent 
 -2.45            10% 
 -2.4              0%
 -2.35             0%
```

However, in SAS 9.3 I get these results:

```
MinPoint    Cumpercent 
 -2               10%
```

The first problem in the SAS 9.3 output is that observations with `CUMPERCENT=0` are excluded. The second problem is that the minpoints are wrong.

Comment: @DomPazz dude  have a look at the dataset

Comment: You don't have any missing values in your example data. Can you elaborate on the exclusion of missing values? Also I can't reproduce the issue in SAS 9.4; I get an output dataset from `PROC UNIVARIATE` with 341 observations, not 3 or 1 as you've shown.

Comment: Also, a good place to look for what has changed between SAS versions is the documentation for each release, which always includes a "What's New" section that details changes, enhancements, etc. since the previous major release.

Comment: I have sas 9.3 TS level 1M1 and I also get 341 obs, it looks like sas extends the endpoints to cover all data. If I add a `(where=(value>=-2.5 and value<=2.45))` I get just 1 obs with `_MINPT_=-2.5 _OBSPCT_=100 _COUNT_=1`